# how to arrange data according to month name in Flask

Tags: python, flask, html-table

```
I have a Flask code like this:

    <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>YEAR</th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <th>May</th>
                <th>Jun</th>
                <th>Jul</th>
                <th>Aug</th>
                <th>Sep</th>
                <th>Oct</th>
                <th>Nov</th>
                <th>Dec</th>                
            </thead>
            <tbody><tr>
                    {% for avg, count, date  in data %}                    

                    <td>{{ avg }} [{{ count }}] [{{ date }}]</td>                

                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

An it is generating table like this..

[image]

How to generate table according to month-name (ignore year column).
Like January data under January column, February data under Feb column an so on...

Comment: Please post your raw data (real or contrived) so that those trying to present a solution can easily test without having to guess and/or create their own.